# Magento 2: How to add color picker in ui form

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid, uicomponent, ui-form

I am developing new extension in which I need to add color picker and date picker as well in an admin form. I am developing form using a component. Please check sample screenshot of the form field. I want to implement in UI Form. Could any one help me for that?

[image]

Thank You in Advance

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Comment: I found your question :) I'll write the answer when I have a free time. It will be like text field (hidden) with a colorpicker and HEX-value of the color.

Comment: Hi, could you give answer please

Comment: This is possible & need to add color picker script. I wil send you 100% solution

Comment: I also want to add color picker to category attribute. Could anyone help please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently needed to add a color picker to a category form. Here is what wound up working:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="my_color_picker">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/form/element/color-select</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/color-select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Color Picker</item>
                    <item name="labelVisible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category_form</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It's essentially a generic text input, but we've defined a unique `elementTmpl` and `component`.

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/color-select.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'mageUtils',
    'jquery',
    'jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker'
], function (Element, utils, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible: true,
            label: '',
            error: '',
            uid: utils.uniqueid(),
            disabled: false,
            links: {
                value: '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataScope }'
            }
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },

        initColorPickerCallback: function (element) {
            var self = this;

            $(element).ColorPicker({
                onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                    self.value(hex);
                    $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                },
                onBeforeShow: function () {
                    $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                }
            }).bind('keyup', function(){
                $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm initiating the color picker with an `afterRender` callback. In my use case the element was not rendered on the page when my component was initialized, so adding the color picker in the `initial` method did not work for me.

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/color-select.html

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text"
       data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        afterRender: initColorPickerCallback,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }"/>
```

You'll also want to add the color picker css as a layout update, so the filename will vary:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/{frontName}_{controller}_{action}.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**End Result (Input Focus State)**
[image: End Result (Input Focus State)]

Comment: Hi is this work? I tried, its working also but it does not auto fill color code to textbox. Can you please let us know how to solve this? thank you.

Comment: @Vish see post below

Comment: i followed same tutorial but got a problem can u please check [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275929/date-picker-is-overlapping-on-my-color-picker-in-admin-form-magento-2 )

Comment: @pmclain Can you share this module? I also need to add color picker field in category edit page of admin.

Comment: The formElement should be colorPicker to work colorFormat properly.

Answer (score 9):

I added onChange event

```
            $(element).ColorPicker({
            onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                self.value(hex);
                $(el).ColorPickerHide();
            },
            onBeforeShow: function () {
                $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
            },
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                self.value('#'+hex);
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The best way to add color picker in field is .

```
<field name="md_label_background_color">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/color-picker</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/color-picker</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Background Color (hex)</item>
                <item name="labelVisible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category_form</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

No need to addd any file!!

Comment: how can we add it to frontend ui form.I have tried and it don't show color picker shade on it.rest was working.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a colorPicker Component defined in the core.

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/colorPicker.xsd
```

Try adding this to your form:

```
<colorPicker name="colors_picker" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ColorPicker" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/color-picker" template="ui/form/element/color-picker" provider="${ $.parentName }">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Color</label>
        <colorFormat>HEX</colorFormat>
        <colorPickerMode>full</colorPickerMode>
        <dataScope>colors_picker</dataScope>
    </settings>
</colorPicker>
```

Comment: color picker data is not saving in database.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to add colorpicker in admin ui form

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_form.xml

```
<field name="background_color" sortOrder="2" formElement="colorPicker" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/color-picker">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category_slider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Slider background color</label>
        <dataScope>background_color</dataScope>
        <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/color-picker</elementTmpl>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <colorPicker class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ColorPicker">
            <settings>
                <colorFormat>hex</colorFormat>
                <colorPickerMode>full</colorPickerMode>
            </settings>
        </colorPicker>
    </formElements>
</field>
```